# Missing spring-web.jar when deploying with WTP to Websphere

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-wtp, websphere-8

I've build a spring-based web project in Eclipse using Maven. Dependencies and class path are correct and the deployment assembly also lists spring-web*.jar correctly. However, when I deploy it using WebSphere 8 from within Eclipse the mentioned JAR file is missing from the created libs folder under .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2*\WEB-INF\lib . This JAR however is listed under the module section as a submodule for the container. I wasn't able to find out, why this JAR is listed there and why it is not copied to the LIB folder.

It works with a Tomcat server, it works when I export the WAR and deploy it manually and it also works when I manually copy the JAR to the lib folder.

Q1: Is this specific to Websphere?

Q2: Why is SPRING-WEB listed as submodule and what effect has this?

Q3: How can I automatically deploy it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in WAS as reported [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=8fde79d3-8ede-4a19-b503-de6c5b75c320)

You can either copy the missing JARs manually or you can use the "Run server with resources on server" option in the "Publishing settings for WebSphere Application Server" server settings.